# LabVIEW Programming for running the machine continuously

Tags: labview

I want to run my Robot in 3 -axes(X,Y,Z) continuously with different values of
x, y, z. Suppose i want the machine to run 100 times. Each time the values of the  x, y, z will be different and each time it will take the values from a table automatically so that while running the machine i don't need to change the values each time. How is it possible in Lab VIEW? I am using Lab VIEW  2011.

Comment: Can you please provide example code? The question is not much clear to me.

Comment: This basically can be done easily in any programming language, so this is not really a question in my opinion but an request for "please make me this LabVIEW program". Please state your question more specific, do you have troubles with the first setup? Hardware communication? Et cetera.

Comment: Actually i am facing proiblem to read data from spreadsheet. in my labVIEW program i modified the 2D straight line move. vi to 3D straight line move.vi. I made 4 arrays 4 controlling the positions of x,y,z and also for velocity.But i don't want it, i need to get the data automatically from spreadsheet and the machine will run according to the values which are pre written in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your spreadsheet in CSV format, you can then read it into a LabVIEW array using **Read from Spreadsheet File** in the `Programming` > `File I/O` palette. You can then use the array functions in the `Programming` > `Array` palette to get the subarrays you need out of the first array. If you want to run the same code multiple times using different values from the spreadsheet then you will probably want to use a For or While loop.

If you carefully read the online help for these functions and try experimenting with them you should be able to work out how to do what you need. If you can't get it to work properly, post a screenshot or (better) VI snippet showing what you have tried and people will be able to offer more specific help.

LabVIEW doesn't have functions to read directly from Excel spreadsheet files, but there are third-party add-ons to do this if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you would be to start learning LabVIEW little bit dipper before writing the code.

Anyway, you can use read from spreadsheet file.vi. Hope the links below will be helpful:
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/glang/read_from_spreadsheet_file/

https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-12287